# I need to write a program to print the following pattern:

Tags: python-3.x

I need to produce the following pattern:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
  1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4
      1 2 3
        1 2
          1
```

I have written a code that produces the same but in a right side up form. i don't understand how to flip it over.

```
for i in range(1, 6 + 1):
    for j in range(1, rows + 1):
        if(j < i):
            print(' ', end = '  ')
        else:
            print(i, end = '  ')
    print()
```

Comment: what is the value of `rows` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: This *somewhat* fails with rows >= 12, honorable mention to [alexanderhurst](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56569000/6655150) for finding the bug in this implementation, and providing another clean solution. However, we can mimic tabulate by using tabs (`\t`) instead of spaces (see at the bottom).

Why not something simpler?

```
rows = 6
l = list(range(rows))

for i in range(rows):
   print(" " * 2*i + " ".join(str(x) for x in l[:rows-i]))
```

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
  1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4
      1 2 3
        1 2
          1
```

Edit: If you want permutations, try these:

```
>>> for i in range(rows):
...    x = " " * 2*i + " ".join(str(x) for x in l[:rows-i])
...    print(x[::-1])

6 5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1  
4 3 2 1    
3 2 1      
2 1        
1
```

```
>>> for i in range(rows, -1, -1):
...    print(" " * 2*i + " ".join(str(x) for x in l[:rows-i]))
... 

          1
        1 2
      1 2 3
    1 2 3 4
  1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

```
>>> for i in range(rows, -1, -1):
...   x = " " * 2*i + " ".join(str(x) for x in l[:rows-i])
...   print(x[::-1])
... 

1          
2 1        
3 2 1      
4 3 2 1    
5 4 3 2 1  
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Bug for larger numbers of rows:

```
>>> rows = 14
>>> l = list(range(rows))
>>> for i in range(rows):
...    print(" " * 2*i + " ".join(str(x) for x in l[:rows-i]))
... 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
          0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
            0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
              0 1 2 3 4 5 6
                0 1 2 3 4 5
                  0 1 2 3 4
                    0 1 2 3
                      0 1 2
                        0 1
                          0
```

Hotfix 1: use tabs. This can work okay if your tab length is the same as me and you use <20 rows on max screen width (well, otherwise alexanderhurst's solution might not solve your problem either).

```
>>> for i in range(rows):
...    print("\t" * i + "\t".join(str(x) for x in l[:rows-i]))
... 
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
            0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
                0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
                    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
                        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
                            0   1   2   3   4   5   6
                                0   1   2   3   4   5
                                    0   1   2   3   4
                                        0   1   2   3
                                            0   1   2
                                                0   1
                                                    0
```

Hotfix 2: add / remove spaces according to number length (e.g. using `log(x)` or `len(str(x))` or similar) but it becomes too complex.

Comment: As far as going beyond your terminal size, pretty much nothing will look good. Tabs will work just fine up until the number of characters in a cell passes the tab length. It looks like for you this would be 3 however with a terminal width 157 columns my output is unreadable in terminal with any input count past 42. Even with tabulate which makes each column width equal to the longest single element to be printed in it. With tabulate this information could remain readable in a text file with a text editor for much longer but I think we can all agree that probably serves absolutely no use.

Answer (score 1):

This solution resembles yours with a few changes
It first prints out the number of spaces needed for the triangle shape
Then it counts up to `count`
and then it moves to the next line

```
num = 6
for i in range(num,0,-1):
    print('  '*(num - i), end='')
    for j in range(i):
        print(j + 1, end=' ')
    print()
```

this does have an odd effect if you use a value greater than 10

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 
        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 
          1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
            1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
              1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
                1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
                  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
                    1 2 3 4 5 6 
                      1 2 3 4 5 
                        1 2 3 4 
                          1 2 3 
                            1 2 
                              1
```

You can use tabulate to keep everything in its column. Here I also used a list comprehension to reduce code size.
code:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
count = 16
numbers = [[''] * (count - i) + [j+1 for j in range(i)] for i in range(count, 0, -1)]
print(tabulate(numbers))
```

output:

```
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11  12  13  14  15
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9   10  11  12  13  14
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8   9   10  11  12  13
            1  2  3  4  5  6   7   8   9   10  11  12
               1  2  3  4  5   6   7   8   9   10  11
                  1  2  3  4   5   6   7   8   9   10
                     1  2  3   4   5   6   7   8    9
                        1  2   3   4   5   6   7    8
                           1   2   3   4   5   6    7
                               1   2   3   4   5    6
                                   1   2   3   4    5
                                       1   2   3    4
                                           1   2    3
                                               1    2
                                                    1
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count backwards with `range()`:

```
for i in range(6, 0, -1):
    for j in range(1, rows + 1):
        if(6-j >= i): # if i = 6, doesn't activate. i=5, activates once. i=4, activates twice, etc.
            print(' ', end = ' ')
        else:
            print(i, end = ' ')
    print()
```

Comment: What is `rows` here?

Comment: Same thing it was in the original question (that is, not specified).

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can see you are trying to make the form:

```
     1
    21
   321
  4321
 54321
654321
```

So the loops need to be reversed and you need to add a space filler section.

```
rows = 6
for i in range(1, rows+1):
    out = ''
    for j in range(1, rows):
        out += ' '

    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        out += str(j)
    print(out)

    rows -=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A 1 line statement using list comprehension would be

```
pattern = '\n'.join((' ' * 2 * i) + ' '.join(str(n) for n in range(1, num + 1)) for i, num in enumerate(range(6, -1, -1)))
```

For clarification, you can have a look at the below commands executed on Python interactive terminal.

```
>>> pattern = '\n'.join((' ' * 2 * i) + ' '.join(str(n) for n in range(1, num + 1)) for i, num in enumerate(range(6, -1, -1)))
>>> 
>>> print(pattern)                                                                                            
1 2 3 4 5 6
  1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4
      1 2 3
        1 2
          1

>>>
```

It is suggested to use functional approach for this kind of repetitive work (If you want to try with multiple samples).

```
def print_num_triangle(n=6):
    """
    1 2 3 4 5 6
      1 2 3 4 5
        1 2 3 4
          1 2 3
            1 2
              1
    """

    pattern = '\n'.join((' ' * 2 * i) + ' '.join(str(n) for n in range(1, num + 1)) for i, num in enumerate(range(n, -1, -1)))
    print(pattern)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_num_triangle(10)

    # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    #   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    #     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    #       1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    #         1 2 3 4 5 6
    #           1 2 3 4 5
    #             1 2 3 4
    #               1 2 3
    #                 1 2
    #                   1
    #                     

    print_num_triangle(7)
    # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    #   1 2 3 4 5 6
    #     1 2 3 4 5
    #       1 2 3 4
    #         1 2 3
    #           1 2
    #             1

    print_num_triangle() # default -> 6
    # 1 2 3 4 5 6
    #   1 2 3 4 5
    #     1 2 3 4
    #       1 2 3
    #         1 2
    #           1
```